# How can i add web service to my web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application that process payment to another site. The scenario is my web application will send complete information (e.g. total payment, customer information,.etc) to a partner payment site. And then the partner payment site will respond information to my web application whether the the payment process is successful.
My problem is how can i create or add web service to my application so that the partner site will able to send me back the status of payment and that my web app will be able to update its database. 
Im new to mvc and i need an EXAMPLE how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Add in your solution a webapi to the needed job. There are plenty of webapi examples in the internet.

Comment: does web api has the capability of restricting the domains that will access my site?

Comment: Sorry but i cannot understand the question.

Comment: okay. i need to give permission to a site that can access my web app. is it possible with web api?

Comment: You mean to have some url(s) that can access your webapi? You can detect client ip.

Comment: okay. thank you for the idea. I'm really new to building web application.

Comment: You are welcome :). We are pass through this step :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add a web-api project the will provide you a rest web service "platform" or use wcf if you prefer to do this in other ways.

Read Some more to find what suits you the most:

- [Web-Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api)
- [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: so i will i need to create another project or just include the web api to my already built project?

Comment: I would open a new project(dll) in the same solution.